# How can I write aggs query in hibernate search

Tags: elasticsearch, nhibernate, hibernate-search

How can I write aggregation query  on a particular term in hibernate search using elastic search.Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to perform faceting (which is one way of using aggregations), Hibernate Search provides a dedicated feature: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#query-faceting

If you want to aggregate for other purposes, I'm afraid this is not possible (yet) using Hibernate Search. We are planning to introduce it in Hibernate Search 6, though (or at least allow to perform aggregations by bypassing Hibernate Search's abstractions).

Comment: Thanks yoann for your reply.